# vuejs invoice input binding processors

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to do invoice four, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do it.
First of all, to give an example:
Quantity 1 Unit Price 2000 Percent (18) = net total "2360".
and then if the user changes "net_total" I want the unit price to change.
Then if the user wants to apply a discount, I want it to be reflected in net_total as a percentage, or if he writes it as a currency, not a percentage. It will write net total.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        invoiceItem: [
            {
                name: "",
                quantity: 0,
                unit_price: 0,
                vat_rate: 18,
                net_total: 0,
                showDesc: false,
                showDiscount: false,
                description: '',
                discount_value: 0,
                discount_rate:'usd'
            },
        ],
    },
    methods: {
        addInvoice() {
            this.invoiceItem.push({
                name: "",
                quantity: 0,
                unit_price: 0,
                vat_rate: 18,
                net_total: 0,
                showDesc: false,
                showDiscount: false,
                description: '',
                discount_value: 0,
                discount_rate:'usd'
            });
        },
        removeIncoiceItem(index) {
            this.invoiceItem.splice(index, 1);
        },
    },
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<section class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:17%">Name</th>
                <th style="width:14%">Quantity</th>
                <th style="width:14%">Unit Price</th>
                <th style="width:15%">Vat Rate</th>
                <th style="width:14%">Net Total</th>
                <th style="width:15%">Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <div v-for="(item, index) in invoiceItem" :key="index" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" v-model="item.name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" v-model="item.quantity">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" v-model="item.unit_price">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <select v-model="item.vat_rate">
                        <option value="18">%18</option>
                        <option value="8">%8</option>
                        <option value="1">%1</option>
                        <option value="0">%0</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="text" v-model="item.net_total">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <button
                        class="btn btn-primary"
                        v-if="!item.showDesc" @click="item.showDesc = !item.showDesc">Add Description
                    </button>
                    <button
                        class="btn btn-secondary"
                        v-if="!item.showDiscount" @click="item.showDiscount = !item.showDiscount">Add Discount
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" @click="removeIncoiceItem(index)">X</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" v-if="item.showDesc">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="description">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" v-if="item.showDiscount">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="discount_value">
                        <select class="form-select-new" v-model="item.discount_rate">
                            <option value="dollar">USD</option>                                       <option value="percent">&</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div style="margin-top:10px">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="addInvoice()"> Add Item</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't agree with anything I say

Comment: For example; Suppose the user changed net_total. I want the necessary action to be taken when the total changes

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to create two calculate methods, one when the `net_total` changed and one when one of the parameters (like the `unit_price`) changed. I assume your `unit_price` is the gross unit price.

You have to add the `@change` property on the inputs.

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" v-model="item.unit_price" @change="changed(item)">
</div>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="text" v-model="item.net_total" @change="changedTotal(item)">
</div>

<!--
Here was also the 'v-model="item.discount_value"' missing.
<input type="text" placeholder="discount_value" v-model="item.discount_value" @change="changed(item)">
-->
<!--
<input type="text" v-model="item.quantity" @change="changed(item)">
<input type="text" v-model="item.unit_price" @change="changed(item)">
<select v-model="item.vat_rate" @change="changed(item)">
<input type="text" v-model="item.net_total" @change="changedTotal(item)">
<select class="form-select-new" v-model="item.discount_rate" @change="changed(item)">
-->
```

An then use the following methods to calculate the gross to net and net to gross.

```js
changed(item) {
    let sum = item.quantity * item.unit_price;
    if (item.discount_rate == 'percent')
        sum -= sum*parseFloat((item.discount_value / 100))
    else
        sum -= item.discount_value
    let percent = parseFloat((item.vat_rate/100)+1);
    item.net_total = sum/percent;
},
changedTotal(item) {
    let percent = parseFloat((item.vat_rate/100)+1);
    var gross = item.net_total * percent;
    if (item.discount_rate == 'percent')
        gross = gross*parseFloat((item.discount_value / 100)+1)
    else
        gross += item.discount_value
    item.unit_price = gross / item.quantity;
},
```

It could also be possible via the [vue watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers), but I think this would be too complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but there must be a simpler way. I tried the way you wrote but it doesn't apply most of the inputs

Comment: Have you added the `@change="changed(item)"` on every control which should process the change? See in the HTML comment.